# Is there a function for sleeping a set amount in C++ for windows?

Tags: c++, windows

I know there is one in C, `Sleep(ms)`, but is there one for C++? I am trying to return an error, then print to the console, then sleep enough for the user to read it before returning the errorcode. Code in C would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main (int argc, const char *argv[]) {
  char *err = "Have an error!";
  printf("Error: %s. Program terminating in 5 seconds...", err);
  Sleep(5000);
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: C++ can call C functions, so...

Comment: Can it call C headers, too? like i include <windows.h> at the top?

Comment: Code in C++ would be the same: `Sleep(5000);`. Doesn't your C++ compiler come with `Windows.hpp`? That would be the C++ equivalent of `windows.h`.

Comment: C++ can deal with most C code without modification. Although there are some quirks and gotchas, C++ is largely a superset of C.

Answer (score 0):

You could include <windows.h> and just call the WinApi function Sleep just as you would from C. This is mostly pure C++ :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, const char *argv[]) {
   string err = "Have an error!";
   cout << "Error: " << err << ". Program terminating in 5 seconds..." << endl;

   std::chrono::milliseconds timespan(5000);
   std::this_thread::sleep_for(timespan);
  
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: `calcc.cpp: In function 'int main(int, const char**)': calcc.cpp:33:5: error: 'this_thread' has not been declared: this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(5000));`

Comment: @COArSeD1RTxxx The code is fine, [`std::this_thread::sleep_for()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) is in `<thread>`.  Are you sure you are compiling with C++11 enabled?

Comment: One could also sleep for `seconds{5}` or `5s`.

Comment: I compiled with g++. Windows box I was testing on didn't have Microsoft's VS, but did have WSL...